# Show nested structure side-by-side without absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have a nested html structure, where you can click on a list item, and have sub list items appear next to the selected list item.

[image: list structure with selected items]

I am able to achieve something close to this using flexbox, however, every increased depth of items is not offset vertically, and it isn't possible to use a nested html structure.

The only way I have been able to achieve something similar to the photo, is by using absolute positioning, but I'd like to avoid that if at all possible.

Any ideas on how something like this could be achievable?

```css
.item {
    width: 300px;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    padding: 1rem;
    border: 1px solid black
}

.level1 {
    background-color: darksalmon;
}

.level2 {
    background-color: deepskyblue;
}

.level3 {
    background-color: darkorchid;
}

.main {
    background-color: darkgreen;
}

.level2.expanded > ul {
  position: absolute;
    left: 342px;
    top: 67px;
}

.level3.expanded > ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 334px;
    top: 155px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="main">
      <ul>
        <div class="item level1">Item 1</div>
        <div class="item level2 expanded">
          <div>Item 2</div>
          <ul>
            <div class="item level2">Item 2.1</div>
            <div class="item level2">Item 2.2</div>
            <div class="item level2">Item 2.3</div>
            <div class="item level3 expanded">
              <div>Item 2.3</div>
              <ul>
                <div class="item level3">Item 2.3.1</div>
                <div class="item level3">Item 2.3.2</div>
                <div class="item level3">Item 2.3.3</div>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="item level2">Item 2.5</div>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="item level1">Item 3</div>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think, for this kind of thing, absolute positioning is probably the best option. What makes you reluctant to use that option? Also, please share your “*[mcve]*” code in your question, including your best attempt at css.

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica I've added the code snippet. I'm hesitant to use absolute positioning because I reckon I'll have to calculate where the position of items are supposed to be using JavaScript and I'd like to have the browser handle the positioning of the elements automatically.

  

I considered using invisible elements to create the top offset using the flexbox approach, but then I have a hacky solution and the html isn't nested to I think it might take a hit in accessibility

Comment: You really shouldn't need any JavaScript to calculate positioning, demo: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wyj51kot/ if you're designing for smaller displays where the menus might be off-screen, then you should probably use a more traditional one-column menu structure (https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wyj51kot/1/); though if you try using that menu, you may see the difficulties. As an improvement the '[checkbox hack](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/)' can be used: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wyj51kot/2/

Comment: Thanks @DavidsaysreinstateMonica, a few nice solutions. I was trying to figure this out as I was sure it could be done with Vanilla CSS. Your first fiddle would have even sufficed. Would you please post a proper answer for the rest of the SO community? Much obliged!